# Strange php problem

Tags: php

The following code:

```
print_r($_GET);
echo '<br />';
echo isset($_GET['logout'])?'yes':'no';
```

prints:

```
Array ( [logoout] => )
no
```

Why is it printing "no" instend of "yes"?

Comment: Because it's `logoout` with two `o`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

logoout  - double "o"

Comment: It is simple. You don't use strict mode in PHP ;-). Use this function http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_error_reporting.asp at the beginning of your script with E_ALL level.